# Keyboard shortcut to switch to an application by name?

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts, application-switcher, productivity

Is there a tool that will let me do the following sequence?

1. Type a keyboard shortcut
2. Type in the name of an application currently open on some desktop
3. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to switch to that desktop, and bring that application into focus instantly

(The Chromium plugin [Vimium](http://vimium.github.io/) provides an analogous feature for browser tabs: pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> in that environment to list all tabs, type in some words to filter by title, and hit enter to bring up the selected tab.)

Comment: Isn't this what Unity search already does? Press Alt, write start of application, press enter. Said Application comes up.

Answer (score 5):

In the same System Settings window that [Mechanical snail](https://askubuntu.com/users/64389/mechanical-snail) mentions, you can configure a new Custom Shortcut (two places up the tree from Global Shortcuts). Make it of **type** `Command/URL` with the following **action**:

```
xdotool windowactivate `xdotool search --name Vimperator | head -1`
```

Of course, change `Vimperator` to the name of the desired application.

Answer (score 2):

If you use KDE, you can do this using KRunner (KDE's run dialog/toolbar). KRunner provides functionality to search the titles of running windows; you just need to add a global keyboard shortcut to activate it.

## Setup

Open `systemsettings` and browse to "Global Keyboard Shortcuts". In the "KDE component" dropdown, select "Run Command Interface" to look at the shortcuts for KRunner. Scroll to "Run Command (runner "Windows" only)", click on it, and specify a keystroke to use (I have <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>):

[image: Set keystroke]

Click Apply and close System Settings.

## Usage

Press the shortcut you chose to bring up KRunner. Start typing the title of a window. Once you've narrowed it down to the window you want, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to switch to its virtual desktop and focus the window. You can also click on the window in the drop-down list:

[image: Window run dialog]

Comment: Thanks -- this is good to know. Should have mentioned that I'm using default Ubuntu 13.04 settings (Unity, no KDE)... Any equivalents you know of?

Comment: Krunner will open a new instance of an application. The OP requests a keyboard shortcut to bring a running application to focus. I had this configured once (possibly KDE 3) so I'll see if I can concoct an answer.

Comment: Is this still possible in kde5? Can't find such option in settings

Comment: Answered my own question. In case there's a better approach to do it I'd like to know it :)

Answer (score 1):

Found nasty solution for kde5.

**If you want to have full list of windows with search by titles:**

1. Go to System Settings -> Workspace -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts
2. Create new Global shortcut -> Command/URL (by right click)
3. Tick the checkbox to the right of the name
4. In Trigger tab select desired key combination
5. In Action tab type `/usr/local/bin/krunner-search-by-windows.sh`
6. Create file `/usr/local/bin/krunner-search-by-windows.sh` with following
   content:
   `#!/bin/bash
   qdbus org.kde.krunner /App querySingleRunner windows "" 
   sleep 0.4
   xdotool type 'window '
   xdotool key "shift+BackSpace"`
7. Make file executable and give run permission to all
   `chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/krunner-search-by-windows.sh`

Note the space after 'window'.

Now you're able to get list of opened windows by specified shortcut and search by this list as you type;

**If you only want search by titles without full windows list:**

1. Go to System Settings -> Workspace -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts
2. Create new Global shortcut -> D-bus Command (by right click)
3. Tick the checkbox to the right of the name
4. In Trigger tab select desired key combination
5. In Action tab insert following information:

   - Remote application : org.kde.krunner
   - Remote Object      : /App
   - Function           : querySingleRunner
   - Arguments          : windows ""
6. Done

Answer (score 0):

[windownow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/windownow/0.9.5) seems to do what you want.

From the package page:

> Switch desktop's windows by typing their titles, name, etc.

You can install it with:

```
$ [sudo] pip install windownow
# Then reload your shell and start the program 
$ windownow
```

On the first run it will ask you to choose keyboard combination to invoke the `windownow` window.

The only issue I found so far is that for some windows (e.g Chrome) the `windownow` window appears in the background instead of foreground (i.e "above" all the windows). Except that I'm pretty content with this solution.

Comment: As it stands, your post isn't of a very good quality. Please provide more info. Consider these: How does user install windownow ? How does it work and what is it's basic functions ? How can it be bound to a shortcut ?

Comment: @Serg Added more info, hope it's better now.